# How do I create PowerBI charts by typing a description of the chart

Tags: visualization, powerbi

At [this point in the PowerBI intro video](https://youtu.be/_OOyJfszJXY?t=60) they say "no need to learn a new language" and demonstrate how a visualisation and inputs are picked by typing a description.

Where do I find this functionality in PowerBI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also in Preview for Power BI Desktop:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-december-feature-summary/#QandA

Comment: Thanks, this was a big help!
For others reading, the functionality is called "Q and A".
Access by clicking the **"Ask a question"** button in either Desktop or online version.
In Desktop you need to :
 a) Have the December 2017 version or newer
 b) Activate the feature preview by going to:  File -> Options and settings -> Options -> Global -> Preview Features -> Q&A

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this on my Power BI account and it looks like it only shows up for dashboards in "My Workspace" rather than any shared workspaces I've created. (I haven't been able to find documentation that specifies why this might be though.)

Comment: Thanks Alexis, this is appearing in my shared workspaces for both dashboards and reports, not sure why it wouldn't for you.